# How versatile are the parts in a lego pirate ship set?

Tags: sets, boat

I am looking at buying one of the pirate ship sets, such as [6285-1: Black Seas Barracuda](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6285-1),
however, I am concerned the parts in the set are too specialized, and could not be easily adapted to make custom creations. The three main parts are: the pieces of the ship's hull, the masts, and the sails. Are there any uses for these parts outside of making other pirate ships?

Comment: I have a mast and rigging from [6270: Forbidden Island](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6270-1), I haven't really found them to be all that useful otherwise. Of course, that could just be my lack of imagination... ;)

Comment: Is the entire black part of the mast, except for the round base of the crow's nest, just one piece?

Comment: If you don't know what the parts inside look like, keep in mind you can check [an inventory](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6285-1) of the set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(promoting this from comment to answer, since it now has pictures)

In my experience, they're not that useful.  I have a mast and rigging from [6270: Forbidden Island](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6270-1), and more rigging from [6261: Raft Raiders](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6261-1).  The [mast from 6261 is more useful](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4318) (and has been in 20 sets) because it also has the two finger hinges, which make it a bit more versatile than the two mast pieces of 6270 ([first part](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4844) [8 sets], [second part](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2537a) [3 sets]).  The [mast platform](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2539) is quite reusable, given its generic shape.

All the pieces apart look like this:

[image]

And you can combine the small rigging and mast platform to make a rudimentary TIE Fighter:

[image: rudimentary tie fighter]

Comment: Nice work on the TIE fighter - it proves that imagination is the only real limit

Answer (score 11):

ALL parts can be used for something other than the original theme.

[Here's an example of a use for the boat hull by Flickr user 2 Much Caffeine:](http://www.flickr.com/photos/24681250@N07/6897018407/)

There's also a rather humorous saying that goes: "All parts are space parts".  It's equally applicable to any other theme.